# Where can I find some documentation for BlueZ?

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth

I am developing an android application for an embedded device that uses android 2.1. The bluetooth protocol stack is bluez. I cannot find any documentation related to bluez, and the source code is quite hard to read as it is not commented at all! There seems to have been a bluez wiki, but that site has been down for some time now...

Any help regarding where I might be able to find any help/documentation regarding how the bluez stack functions will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually not all Android devices use BlueZ stack as the underline bluetooth stack. It would be a good idea to stick with Android SDK bluetooth API if you want portability.

This being said, http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/ is a nice bluez tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

Aniruddha, you may want to try using DBus Interface to invoke BlueZ APIs.

Answer (score 2):

For the official BlueZ documentation you can obtain it from their git site:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

For additional information you can visit BlueZ site: http://www.bluez.org/

Depending on the platform you're using you may need to use D-Bus. There are a lot of different D-Bus libraries depending on which language you're using. I will warn that using BlueZ directly has a high learning curve and requires some knowledge of the Bluetooth specification.

For Android I would recommend using the Bluetooth classes that are packaged with the Android Platform API if possible.

Answer (score 0):

For Android application you should refer to the Android APIs. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html

Application need not know the underlying BlueZ libraries and its functionalities

Comment: Unfortunately I need to implement features in bluetooth (namely, as an A2DP sink) that are not supported by android 2.1! So although the android API functions for this are available, I cannot use them to develop an application for 2.1. Upgrading the OS is not an option for me (Hardware/cost constraints). However, the BlueZ stack does support this, so I must use the bluez API and develop using the NDK.